# R converting integer column to 3 factor columns based on digits

Tags: r

I have a column of int's like this:

```
idNums
   2
 101
  34
  25
   8
 ...
```

I need to convert them to 3 factor columns like this:

```
digit1        digit2         digit3
  0             0              2
  1             0              1
  0             3              4
  0             2              5
  0             0              8
 ...           ...            ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fun solution using the modular arithmetic operators `%%` and `%/%`:

```
d <- c(2, 101, 34, 25, 8)
res <- data.frame(digit1 = d %/% 100, 
                  digit2 = d %% 100 %/% 10,  
                  digit3 = d %% 10)
#   digit1 digit2 digit3
# 1      0      0      2
# 2      1      0      1
# 3      0      3      4
# 4      0      2      5
# 5      0      0      8
```

Note that it has the minor -- but nice -- side benefit of returning **numeric** values for each of the columns. If you do, however, want **factor** columns instead, just follow up with this command:

```
res[] <- lapply(res, as.factor)

all(sapply(res, class)=="factor")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @RichieCotton - Thanks. I thought it was amusing that treating the integers as numbers, rather than strings felt like the unexpected approach.

Answer (score 5):

Use `formatC` and `strsplit`.

```
idNums <- c(2, 101, 34, 25, 8)
idChars <- formatC(idNums, width = 3, flag = "0")
idChars <- strsplit(idChars, "")
data.frame(
  digits1 = sapply(idChars, function(x) x[1]),  
  digits2 = sapply(idChars, function(x) x[2]),
  digits3 = sapply(idChars, function(x) x[3])  
)
```

---

It's a little cleaner using the `stringr` package. Replace the call to `strsplit` with

```
str_split_fixed(idChars, "", 3)
```

Comment: Rather than post a very similar solution, here's the one-liner I came up with: `t(sapply(strsplit(sprintf("%003d",idNums),""), as.integer))`

Comment: You could also use data.frame(do.call(rbind, idChars)) and then add the column names in afterward.

Answer (score 3):

I thought Richie Cottons use of formatC was kewl so I incorporated it:

```
testdat <- read.fwf(textConnection(formatC(idNums, width = 3, flag = "0")  ), 
                    widths=c(1,1,1), 
                    col.names=c("digit1", "digit2", "digit3")
                    )
testdat
#------------
  digit1 digit2 digit3
1      0      0      2
2      1      0      1
3      0      3      4
4      0      2      5
5      0      0      8
```